# Custom ListView Repeating Itself

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

Here is my `getView()` method:

```
public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        int rowType = getItemViewType(pos);

        if (convertView == null) {

            switch (rowType) {


            case 1:

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.single_class_select_row_header, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.label = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvSingleClassSelectHeader);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                break;
            case 2:

                final int newPos = getRealPosition(pos);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.single_class_select_row, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.chkSession);
                holder.mainLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.llSingleClassLayout);

                holder.phase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phase);
                holder.class_info = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.class_info);
                holder.phase.setText(getListObject(pos).phase);
                holder.class_info.setText(getListObject(pos).info);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

                holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            // edit out 
                        }
                    }
                });

                holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                             // edit out  
                                         }
                    }
                });

                holder.phase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                                   // edit out
                        }
                    }
                });


                break;
            }

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        return convertView;
    }
```

Can anyone see why?  I have looked at other examples, but because I am overriding `getItemViewType()` because of headers in the middle of the list, no examples match my circumstances since I am doing things differently.

It seems that I should put the `setOnClickListner`'s below the `if-block`, but the I have problem with my `holder` variable not being initialized while other instances of it need it to be `final`.

Comment: You need to set whatever data **outside** of the `if` block where you test the `convertView` otherwise you'll be setting the data only when that view is null(and continue to get only that data as the view is recycled).

Comment: @Luksprog  that was it.  I just had to change things up to get that to work to make all of the `holder` variables happy.  I get the concept now.  you want to recycle UI views, not data!  (you can mark as answer if you wish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the data(text or what other piece of information you have) *outside* of the `if` block where you test the `convertView` for being `null`. Otherwise you'll set the data only when `convertView` is `null` and as this view will get recycled you'll end up with the same piece of information that was previously set.